# Noob Python Script - Cut down script heaps

Tags: python, optimization

Python noob here, I was just wondering if anyone could help me cut this script down heaps.

I've tried:

`if letter == 'A' or 'B' or 'C'`
but it doesn't seem to work.

So if letter is A, B or C print "Hello"
or if letter is D, E or F print Goodbye.

Any help would be great.

Cheers

```
if letter == 'A':
    print "Hello"
if letter == 'B':
    print "Hello"
if letter == 'C':
    print "Hello"              
if letter == 'D':
    print "GoodBye"
if letter == 'E':
    print "GoodBye"       
if letter == 'F':
    print "GoodBye"
```

Answer (score 6):

To cut down on repetition, use `in`:

```
if letter in ('A', 'B', 'C'):
    print "Hello"
elif letter in ('D', 'E', 'F'):
    print "GoodBye"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if letter  in 'ABC': # if letter is in ABC we will print Hello and go no further
    print "Hello"             
elif letter in 'DEF': # if letter is not in ABC we will get here 
    print "GoodBye"
else:  # else it is in neither string 
    print "letter not in any string"
```

`elif's` are only evaluated when the preceding `if` statement is `False`, using `in` we can shorten the check to one statement for each outcome, if we get no match for `ABC` or `DEF` we will end up in the `else` and let the user know the letter is not in either `ABC` or `DEF`.

`if letter == 'A' or 'B' or 'C'` would need to be:

```
`if letter == 'A' or  letter == 'B' or letter =='C'`
```

In your case `if letter == 'A' or 'B' or 'C'` will always be `True` so whether letter is in `ABC` or not you will `print Hello`.

You might want to use `if letter.upper()` also in case a user entered `a` or `b` etc..

Comment: love to know what the downvote was for